DAX help, best way to find a sum with multiple filters having used SUMIFS in excel
I am trying to understand the best way to add a column to my table using DAX that captures the sum of a sales value between a.) the last 31 days and b.) filtered based on a unique identifier.
In Excel, I would do the following with SUMIFS function
Column K being the date ranges
Column A being the unique identifier
Column X being the value to sum
=IFERROR((SUMIFS(X:X,A:A,A493,K:K,">="&K493-30,K:K,"<="&K493))," ")
Hope you can help with the most efficient equation I should be learning!
I've tried Sumx and Calculate with fitlers but cannot get it to work correctly.

Here is an example:
I have a User Table that has an unique value for the user ID and a Sales Table that has the user ID for the sale, a date of sale, and a value for the sale.
We want to find the total sales for each user over the last 31 days.

Create Calculated Column on the User Table:
Last 31 Day Sales (Calculated Column) = 
    VAR thisUser = [User ID] //sets this value outside of Calculate context
    RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Value]),
        FILTER(Sales, 
            Sales[User ID] = thisUser &&
            Sales[Sale Date] <= TODAY() &&
            Sales[Sale Date] >= TODAY() - 31
        )
)

Note: this answer was created on 08/29/2024, which is the result of the Today() function.
This calculated column will filter the Sales table by the user id, and sales made in the last 31 days. Then it will sum the value and return it.
Below are the input and output tables for this example:
Output User Table:



User ID
Name
Last 31 Day Sales (Calculated Column)




1
John Smith
20


2
Jane Doe
14


3
Bob Bob
10



Sales Data Table:



Sale ID
Sale Date
User ID
Value




4
07/01/2024
1
3


1
08/20/2024
1
10


7
08/20/2024
1
6


10
08/20/2024
1
4


5
07/01/2024
2
5


2
08/20/2024
2
5


8
08/20/2024
2
9


3
08/20/2024
3
2


6
08/20/2024
3
8


9
07/01/2024
3
7



